# Restrict network drive to domain users only

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, network-share

In our office we have a domain controller and all employees' machine join the domain. We have new tenants starting soon sharing our internet connection in the office. They won't join the domain and of course shouldn't be able to access our network drive which is on the domain controller.

Is there a way to deny their access to our network drive? The domain controller runs window server 2008 r2.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not split the LAN at the firewall/internet connection into two different LANs either with hardware or VLANs/etc.?

Comment: What TheCleaner said (and I said, too :-)

Comment: Don't forget to mark a correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Ensure that you have not assigned permissions on anything to "anonymous" or "everyone". This will be easiest to check on the share permissions themselves. If you do find those permissions set, change them to "Authenticated users", and you should be good. The only thing this will break will be if you have any non-authenticated access from your own devices; you probably (hopefully) don't. If you do, now's your chance to fix it!

This is a best practice, and is likely already configured. You can do likewise with NTFS permissions on files and folders, but that might take a long time to fix.

But really, you should also segregate the other company into their own VLAN; they shouldn't have to sit in your subnet to share your internet connection.

Comment: The "everyone" security group does not contain the "anonymous logon" user account since Windows XP/Server 2003.

If only users in the domain should be able to access the share the everyone group is the correct one to use. But if only "domain users" or other specific domain security groups should be able to use the share more appropriate groups should be used.

Comment: Good to hear that changed.